# How to change a shader to work for a UI text (Unity3d)

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine, shader

Here is an Overlay shader which works perfectly with UI Images. However, it makes all UI Texts black. I wanted to have a shader which works with UI Text's color (Overlay filter). How do I have to change the following code to work with Texts?

```
Shader "Custom/NewShader"
 {
 Properties
 {
     _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
 }

 SubShader
 {
     Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
     ZWrite Off Lighting Off Cull Off Fog { Mode Off } Blend DstColor SrcColor
     LOD 110

     Pass
     {
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert_vct
         #pragma fragment frag_mult
         #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
         #include "UnityCG.cginc"
         sampler2D _MainTex;
         float4 _MainTex_ST;
         struct vin_vct
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
             float4 color : COLOR;
             float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         struct v2f_vct
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
             fixed4 color : COLOR;
             half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         v2f_vct vert_vct(vin_vct v)
         {
             v2f_vct o;
             o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
             o.color = v.color;
             o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
             return o;
         }
         float4 frag_mult(v2f_vct i) : COLOR
         {
             float4 tex = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);

             float4 final;              
             final.rgb = i.color.rgb * tex.rgb ; //*2
             final.a = i.color.a * tex.a;
             return lerp(float4(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f), final, final.a);

         }
         ENDCG

     }
 }
 }
```

[image: How overlay shader works on an Image (image is also uploaded)] 
[image: overlay shader applied to this image to have the brighten area in the other pic]

Comment: "Overlay shader which works perfectly with UI Images." Can you add a snapshot to show what it means by "it works"?

Comment: I have uploaded the overlay shader applied to an Image

Comment: Any progress on this?